# Iterate Data Table ontop of another Data table and make one table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, join, stored-procedures

I have a question. 
Here is the story, I have Student mark sheet (Table **A**)

```
Name    Course  Marks
Student 01  32472   44
Student 02  32472   80
Student 03  32472   67
Student 04  32472   76
Student 05  32472   56
Student 06  32472   98
Student 07  32472   13
Student 08  32472   68
Student 09  32472   84
Student 10  32472   93
```

And  I have sheet (Table **B** ) for cut off marks for medals.

```
Medel     Course    CutOff
Silver    32472      0-69
Gold      32472      70 -84
Platinum  32472      85 -100
```

Could you please help me to get following sheet (Table) in SQL.

```
Name    Course  Medal
Student 01  32472   Silver
Student 02  32472   Gold
Student 03  32472   Silver
Student 04  32472   Gold
Student 05  32472   Silver
Student 06  32472   Platinum
Student 07  32472   Silver
Student 08  32472   Silver
Student 09  32472   Gold
Student 10  32472   Platinum
```

How Can I join Table A (Student marks sheet) and Table B (Medal cut off marks sheet) then get Final Table ?

Really appreciate your answers/comments.

Thank you
Gayan

Comment: The cutoff for silver doesn't make sense.  What's the value of 50 matter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After your edit:

```
;WITH CteMedals AS(
    SELECT *,
        rStart  = LEFT(CutOff, CHARINDEX('-', CutOff) - 1),
        rEnd    = SUBSTRING(CutOff, CHARINDEX('-', CutOff) + 1, LEN(CutOff) - CHARINDEX('-', CutOff))
    FROM TableB
)
SELECT
    a.Name, a.Course, ISNULL(b.Medal, 'Silver') AS Medal
FROM TableA a
OUTER APPLY(
    SELECT TOP 1 Medal
    FROM CteMedals
    WHERE
        a.Marks BETWEEN rStart AND rEnd
    ORDER BY rEnd DESC
)b
```

---

You can use `OUTER APPLY`:

```
SELECT
    a.Name, a.Course, ISNULL(b.Medal, 'Silver') AS Medal
FROM TableA a
OUTER APPLY(
    SELECT TOP 1 Medal
    FROM TableB
    WHERE
        a.Marks >= CutOff
    ORDER BY CutOff DESC
)b
```